# Java ArrayList contains method doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So when I run this program it shows that the ArrayList "test" doesn't contain the array [5,6] inside the variable "position".When I checked the output, it is  clearly in there and i see that "test" does contain that element.

---

Output:

> [5, 6]
>   [5, 6]
>   false

Code:

```
package arraylisttest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] position = { 5, 6 };
        ArrayList<int[]> test = new ArrayList<>();

        test.add(new int[] {50, 2});
        test.add(new int[] {0, 7});
        test.add(new int[] {5, 6});
        test.add(new int[] {2, 1});

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(position));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.get(2)));
        System.out.println(test.contains(position));
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: ArryList#contains(obejct) will check whethet object is in the list.In your case, position is different the object created by 'new int[] {50, 2}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `List.contains()` will use the `equals()` method to determine if the list contains a given object (q.v. the [source code for ArrayList#contains()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.contains%28java.lang.Object%29)).  It will not compare the two points in each 2D array to see if they be the same.  So even though the point `{5, 6}` logically appears in the list, it is a different object than `position` which you are using for the comparison, and hence the comparison fails.

Note that the following code would have behaved as you expected:

```
int[] position = { 5, 6 };
ArrayList<int[]> test = new ArrayList<>();
test.add(new int[] {50, 2});
test.add(new int[] {0, 7});
test.add(position);
test.add(new int[] {2, 1});

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(position));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.get(2)));

System.out.println(test.contains(position));
```

Comment: Yeah, `contains()`, in this case, would look to see if the array references are the same using `==`.

Comment: Haha, yea I was assuming that Arrays.equals() would have been called during contains() since it is being treated as an object. Meh, I guess it's not implemented that way.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that arrays *don't* override [`Object#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method hence the output you're receiving; rather you can create ArrayList of ArrayLists instead e.g. the code below will output *true*.

```
ArrayList<Integer> position = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 6));
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> test = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5,6));
test.add(y);
System.out.println(test.contains(position));
```

another option would be to leave your current solution as it is, but use a stream to perform a comparison against the other arrays within the list:

```
System.out.println(test.stream().anyMatch(e -> Arrays.equals(e,position)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can only be compared with Arrays.equals().

You should use ArrayList instead:

```
ArrayList<Integer> position = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(5, 6));

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> test = new ArrayList<>();
test.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(50, 2)))
test.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(0, 7)));
test.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(5, 6)));
test.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 1)));


System.out.println(test.contains(position));
```